# Interface javascript with arduino

Tags: javascript, c++, arduino, cross-language

I'm an arduino noob and I'm trying to interface some javascript with arduino. For now all I'm trying to do is move a servomotor in a direction if a js variable is under a certain value and moving it the other way if it's above that value.
I don't have a clue about how i should tackle this, so I'd appreciate any help. I do have the servomotor moving part and the javascript part, I just don't know how to put them together.

Comment: Your question casts a doubt about the research effort you have put so far. In addition to asking SO, you must have tried google, and probably you found (as I just did by googling "arduino javascript") Breakout, Johnny-five, node-ardx.org, and some other projects and blogs... or maybe not.

Comment: Yes, I was just looking on johnny-five and node-ardx, but honestly I'm not very good with node (I only did client-side js) and I'm not sure if I'm really gonna try and pick up two things at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For now all I'm trying to do is move a servomotor in a direction if a
>   js variable is under a certain value and moving it the other way if
>   it's above that value.

Here's how you can accomplish this with [Johnny-Five](https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five):

1. Make sure you have node and npm installed
2. With the Arduino IDE, upload StandardFirmata (File -> Examples -> Firmata -> StandardFirmata) to the Arduino, close the IDE
3. `npm install johnny-five`
4. create a new JS file, save the following in it:

```js
var five = require("johnny-five");
var board = new five.Board();

board.on("ready", function() {

  var servo = new five.Servo(11);

  this.repl.inject({
    move: function(value) {
      var angle = 0;
      if (value > 0) {
        angle = 180;
      }
      servo.to(angle);
    }
  });
});
```

4. With the USB cable plugged in to the board and computer, run the above program in your terminal. Once it's running, call `move(n)` where `n` is any number. Numbers greater than 0 will move the servo to 180°; numbers less than or equal to 0 will move the servo to 0°.